# How to scan an image through scanner in uwp application

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

:)

I am new in uwp application. currently i am developing the uwp desktop 
 application which scan the documents(paper) through scanner and save into data base after image manipulation.so how to scan an image(paper) through scanner in uwp ?

Thanks in advance :) 
have a great day :)

Comment: Please see [ask]. Questions seeking for a tool, library, whatsoever are considered off-topic here.

Comment: ok tank you. :)